# iTextSharp acroFields.SetField method and multiple form fields with same name

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

In case of multiple fields with same name `iTextSharp acroFields.SetField(Name, Value)` sets value for first field only. How to set the value for the rest of the fields? When looping thru the acroFields.Fields the field names are reported as

```
form1[0].#subform[0].TextField1[0] - TextField
form1[0].#subform[0].TextField2[0] - TextField
form1[0].#subform[0].TextField2[1] - TextField
form1[0].#subform[0].TextField2[2] - TextField
```

When using

```
acroFields.SetField("TextField1", Value);
```

the value of text field named as TextField1 is set. there is only one field named as TextField1 so it is fine. However when using

```
acroFields.SetField("TextField2", Value);
```

the value of *first* text field named as TextField2 is set. The rest two fields named as TextField2 are left unset.

The PDF is created with Adobe LiveCycle and saved as Static PDF i.e. it is not Dynamic XFA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you just use the full field name?

```
acroFields.SetField("form1[0].#subform[0].TextField2[0]", Value);
```

Comment: Well the field names are relevant names e.g. CustomerFirstName, CustomerAddress1 and so on. Now if CustomerFirstName happens to be used more than once the acroFields.SetField("CustomerFirstName", Value); sets value only in first field. I am using workaround similar to one suggested by you but I would think the API would provide a simpler way.

Comment: @d456, the workaround is to use the fully qualified name as shown in the answer.